# 5% are left or 5% is left; which is better or correct?

Tags: grammar

So here is the sentence written both ways. Which one is correct and maybe a description why so I can understand why.
Thanks!
/R

Leatherbacks need your help.
They’re endangered and only 5% of the population are left.

OR,

Leatherbacks need your help.
They’re endangered and only 5% of the population is left.

Comment: So been looking at other questions and still can't quite figure out if my example was described. What I gather is that a number of things makes it plural which means using the word  ARE would be correct. Is 5% a plural number here in this case? lol

Answer (score 0):

"Leatherbacks need your help. They’re endangered and only 5% of the population **is** left."

The choice between "is left" and "are left" depends on whether the object(s) you're talking about is(are) singular or plural.

```
There are 5 slices of cake left.
```

*vs.*

```
There is half the cake left.
```

In your case, *the population* is singular and we're talking about a small part of it, so it's "is".

Comment: Cool, thanks CharlieB. I wasn't sure if the 5% population was plural or singular.

Comment: Here population is singular. It's possible to use population as a collective noun, e.g. "A population of Leatherbacks lives off the Atlantic coast of Canada". However here we're talking about __the__ population, so singular.

Comment: It comes down to whether it's something you count. A collective, like population, isn't, so it's treated as singular.  Turtles are, so they'd be plural.